# How to smooth lines in ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, quartz-graphics

i have recorded each point when user touch begin move end the ipad,and then i add these points in to a **CGMutablePathRef** called **path**, then i use following code to draw the lines(path) user touched in ipad.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor]);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);
CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

but these lines didn't look smooth, thanks for your help

Comment: Do you mean the overall line is not smooth because it is a bunch of straight segments or do you mean the segments themselves are jaggy?

Answer (score 5):

You may achieve more smoothness by using the following:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineJoin(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineJoinRound);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), YES);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), YES);
CGContextSetMiterLimit(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2.0);
```

But if you need to draw very smooth lines/curves, then you need to redraw lines by using UIBezierCurve or any other curving algorithms.

Edit: I did some changes in my code for smooth drawing. Check my classic board app: https://itunes.apple.com/app/id493525167

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add this just after you first line.

```
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true);
```

Comment: Did you add this line straight after this line?
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use Cocos2d for perfectly smooth lines. You might want to have a look at this one. https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/smooth-drawing